# SQL query with multiple CASE statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, case

I'm currently working with some data that shows all patients who have undergone a certain type of procedure at a clinic. This procedure category is made up of several codes, each of which represents a more specific procedure that falls under that category. Quality initiatives at the clinic state that patients should have one of these procedures within a certain timeframe; the problem is that each them have different criteria regarding when they could have happened in order to count for quality purposes.

Let me break it down and hopefully explain it a little better. Say we have 3 codes, each representing a type of procedure.

```
CODE    DESCRIPTION
--------------------
1234    Basic procedure
5678    Intermediate procedure
9012    Thorough procedure
```

Now, each of these types of procedure have their own timeframe. The basic version has to have been performed within the past year in order to count. The intermediate one can be from any time in the past *four* years, and the thorough one is good for *ten* years. So a patient who had the intermediate procedure in 2014 would still count for quality purposes, and one who had the thorough procedure in 2009 would still count.

I've got my basic query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    PatientID,
    PatientAge,
    ProcedureCode,
    CodeDescription,
    ServiceDate,
    RenderingProvider,
    VisitType

FROM ServiceDetail

WHERE ProcedureCode IN ('1234','5678','9012')
```

(and yes, the procedure codes are stored as varchars because certain ones in the actual database are alphanumeric)

Now, I wanted to be able to do something using IF/THEN/ELSE logic, which would be a CASE statement in SQL unless I'm mistaken), that can look at the type of code, the service date that the procedure happened, and determine whether or not that procedure counts for quality purposes.

Example in pseudocode:

```
IF ProcedureCode = 5678
AND ServiceDate is between [GETDATE() minus 4 years] and GETDATE()
THEN Yes
```

There'd be identical statements for the two other procedure types with their respective timeframes. I would want the query to only display results when these cases returned true.

My problem is that I know *what* I need to do, but my SQL is rusty and I'm not sure *how* to do it. Basically I'm looking for tips on syntax.

Comment: is there a unique ID for these service details?

Comment: @scsimon  There's a Visit ID field that could be used for that purpose, yes, although I haven't been including it in my query

Comment: You need to query the `ServiceDetail` table right? What's its structure?

Comment: @gaganshera not sure what you mean by structure...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need cases for this, it would only make your query  complicated. You can simply do it like using AND/OR like

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    PatientID,
    PatientAge,
    ProcedureCode,
    CodeDescription,
    ServiceDate,
    RenderingProvider,
    VisitType

FROM ServiceDetail

WHERE (ProcedureCode  = '1234' and ServiceDate Between getdate() AND DATEADD(year, -1, getdate()) OR
(ProcedureCode  = '5678' and ServiceDate Between getdate() AND DATEADD(year, -2, getdate()) ...
```

Comment: Okay yeah this seems like it will probably be the simpler option. Now I appear to be making what will probably turn out to be a really obvious mistake, but SQL Server's errors are so unspecific... I went ahead and tried it your way, but with each part of the WHERE clause on a different line. Got a red squiggle under each of my ORs. Realized I needed to add a closing parenthesis at the end of each line. Red squiggle went away on each OR, but now I've got one on each of the new parenthesis...

Comment: What's the final query that you made?

Comment: You are missing the and getdate() for each of your conditions.....`between dateadd(...) and getdate())` and this is why @EJF is getting errors.

Comment: It's identical to yours but with each line of the WHERE clause on a different line just to keep everything tidy. Each OR statement looked like `(ProcedureCode = ......DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())` but I'd get the syntax error on each instances of OR, so I added the extra closing parenthesis after GETDATE() and the syntax error shifted from OR to the parenthesis

Comment: @scsimon aha! Good catch. I'll bet that's the problem

Comment: Cool. Looks like that worked. Or, even if it doesn't end up exactly solving the problem for the clinic, it at least works for the purposes of this question. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
where
   (procedureCode = '1234' AND ServiceDate 
      Between DATEADD(year, -1, getdate()) and getdate())
or
   (procedureCode = '5678' AND ServiceDate 
       Between DATEADD(year, -4, getdate()) and getdate())
or
  .. etc
```

Comment: Missing the second part of that between in both cases... `(...between dateadd(...) and getdate())`

Comment: No problem, but now you are missing a closing parentheses for each one.  :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your where clause

```
WHERE 
    ProcedureCode IN ('1234','5678','9012')
    AND VisitID IN
    (select VisitID 
    from ServiceDetail 
    where ServiceDate >=
        case 
        when ProcedureCode = 1234 then dateadd(year,-1,getdate())
        when ProcedureCode = 5678 then dateadd(year,-4,getdate())
        when ProcedureCode = 9012 then dateadd(year,-10,getdate())
        end)
    and ServiceDate <= getdate()
```

Or you can explicitly use an `OR` operator for each case of your where clause. I gave `CASE` expression since you explicitly asked for that.

And to fix the syntax errors of others if you choose a direct approach...

```
WHERE 
   (ProcedureCode = '1234' and ServiceDate Between DATEADD(year, -1, getdate()) and getdate()) 
OR
   (ProcedureCode = '5678' and ServiceDate Between DATEADD(year, -2, getdate()) and getdate())
etc...
```